# how to set no cache for all site only for certain hours and no cache always for a specific page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, caching

I have a site where the content of some pages had better to be cached in certain hours, to make faster the navigation back and forward inside the site itself, but those pages must be absolutely no cached on certain other hours, when crucial data updates are put in place. And to make things a little more complex, I need that some pages are never cached since their contents have continuous update.

Any solution to generally refresh pages or something like that has to be absolutely avoided.

But, to make it all a bit more complex once again, in case a specific page has been loaded a certain time before a certain hour, and data have been changed in the meantime (I can check the time or check the db, I suppose with js/jquery action to do it), then I would like to force refreshing that page.

Of course security best practices are needed in case of any js/jquery activity.

So in php and js/jquery how can I get the correct cache management for the needs explained above?

Answer (score 0):

First, browser can auto cache static resources(css/js/img/...).

Second, I think the "cache" you said means you config the cache on your server.If so,I do not suggest you to config it, beacuse PHP needs to run dynamically,if you open the cache on your server,you may not get PHP rendered pages correctly.

That's all.

I suggest that you can use CDN to speed up your static file, such as CSS-File,JS-File,some img. There're lots of free CDN for personal site.

Comment: Sorry but that's not an answer. Yes, of course php runs dinamically, But some pages need a special attention. On certain hours they serve imgs produced on the fly getting data in continuous updating, and so those imgs MUST NOT be chached. BUT on other hours the data that those imgs are based are not updated, so in those hours those imgs HAD BETTER to be cached. And, if you read my post, there are also other situations where I am looking for a granular fine tuning. All that cannot be accomplished by a brute CDN caching. No static files.